# ADB Sideload without custom recovery

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb

Is it possible to use ADB Sideload without custom recovery? For this case on Samsung Devices SM-T211?

I've read in many article to access ADB Sideload we need go through recovery mode and activated sideload mode using either CWM or TWRP.

Thanks

Comment: Even if yes (some newer devices does come with it in stock recovery), the signature verification is still there, and often you can't even find a suitable package to flash (factory images are often in other formats).

Answer (score 0):

Most recoveries will let you use adb sideload but OEM provided recoveries will fail if not fed with signature approved files.